# how to get route table ID in typescript with AWS CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

```
   // create a nat gateway 
   const natGateway = new ec2.CfnNatGateway(this, 'nat-gateway-1',{
      subnetId: mySubnet.subnetId,
      allocationId: new ec2.CfnEIP(this, 'eip-1', {
        domain: 'vpc'
      }).attrAllocationId
    })
    // create a route table
    const routeTable = new ec2.CfnRouteTable(this, 'route-table-1', {
      vpcId: vpc.vpcId,
    })
    // create route
    const route = new ec2.CfnRoute(this, 'route-1', {
      // how to get the route table id?
      routeTableId: 'how to get the id?',
      natGatewayId: 'how to get the id?',
      destinationCidrBlock: vpc.vpcCidrBlock
    })
```

When I create a route table or a nat gateway, how can I get the ID? I am working with typescript

Comment: Did you figure it out? Would like to know as well.

Answer (score 1):

[!Ref on NatGateway resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-natgateway.html#aws-resource-ec2-natgateway-return-values) gives NatGatewayId

Similarly [!Ref on RouteTable resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-route-table.html#aws-resource-ec2-route-table-return-values) give routeTableId

We just need `routeTable.ref` and `natGateway.ref` to get routeTableId and natGatewayId.

```
const natGateway = new ec2.CfnNatGateway(this, "nat-gateway-1", {
  subnetId: mySubnet.ref,
  allocationId: new ec2.CfnEIP(this, "eip-1", {
    domain: "vpc",
  }).attrAllocationId,
});

// create a route table
const routeTable = new ec2.CfnRouteTable(this, "route-table-1", {
  vpcId: this.vpc.ref,
});

// create route
const route = new ec2.CfnRoute(this, "route-1", {
  // how to get the route table id?
  routeTableId: routeTable.ref,
  natGatewayId: natGateway.ref,
  destinationCidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0",
});
```